# CSS Flip Cross Browser Functionality

Tags: css, cross-browser, cross-platform, css-animations

I'm creating an "Artist Table" at the following URL: http://beta2.thrivemusic.com/artists/

As you can see, if you hover over an artist, 3 social icons appear.  However, different bugs appear on different browsers so I need some help with the cross-browser functionality of my code.

FIREFOX: works perfectly
GOOGLE CHROME: Facebook icon link does not work
MOBILE (APPLE + ANDROID): The front side of each artist does not appear on default, the backside is shown instead

Here's how I did it: http://jsfiddle.net/samkimdesign/A7MZ3/2/

```
/* Artists Flip */

#f1_container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 175px;
}

#f1_card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 175px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}

#f1_container:hover #f1_card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  backface-visibility: inherit;
}
.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.face.back {
  display: block;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("http://beta2.thrivemusic.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/flip_back.png");
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 9999999999999;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
Position: relative
```

to the class .face.back.

Mine was the same situation. Adding relative position for the back div worked.